# How to change custom UIButton's image on fly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've create a custom UIButton class to make it look like drop down selection. I've small down arrow image on the right of button. I want to change the button's image to different images such as grey, white or red depending on various conditions. How to do it? Following is my code:

```
class DropDownButton: UIButton {

   let dropDownImageGrey = UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/Grey")
   let dropDownImageWhite = UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/White")
   let dropDownImageRed = UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/Red")

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.frame.width - 108, bottom: 0, right:0)
        self.setImage(dropDownImageGrey, for: [])
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -13, bottom: 0, right:0)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Change image to red one
    dropDownButton.??? // How to change?
}
```

Comment: `dropDownButton.setImage(dropDownButton.dropDownImageRed, for: .normal)`? But you're better off with static constants.

Comment: Tx, did you mean the image constants, these ones => let dropDownImageGrey = UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/Grey") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `setImage` property of `UIButton`,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Change image to red one
    let dropDownButton = DropDownButton()
    dropDownButton.setImage(dropDownButton.dropDownImageRed, for: .normal)
}
```

If the images are added in `Assets.xcassets` then you can use `image literals` or directly use the names like,

```
let dropDownImageGrey = UIImage(named: "Grey")
let dropDownImageWhite = UIImage(named: "White")
let dropDownImageRed = UIImage(named: "Red")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think some answer above work. However, for the sake of production code, I suggest to use enum for the list of images.

```
class DropDownButton: UIButton {

    enum ImageType: String {
      case grey = "Icons/DropDown/Grey"
      case white = "Icons/DropDown/White"
      case red = "Icons/DropDown/Red"

      var image: UIImage? { return UIImage(named: rawValue) }
    }

    var imageType: ImageType = .red {
      didSet {
        setImage(imageType.image, for: .normal)
      }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.frame.width - 108, bottom: 0, right:0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -13, bottom: 0, right:0)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Change image to red one
    dropDownButton.imageType = .red
}
```

Later, if you need to change the image type, simply set the imageType of the button. Like

```
dropDownButton.imageType = .grey
dropDownButton.imageType = .white
```

Comment: Interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum to define the various condition and add a method to get images. Based on the condition you can set the image. Example as below:

Define this enum outside of your class

```
enum DropdownCondition
{
    case condition1

    case condition2

    case condition3

    func getImage() -> UIImage? {
        switch self {
        case .condition1:
            return UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/Grey")
        case .condition1:
            return UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/White")
        case .condition1:
            return UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/Red")
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

in your viewDidLoad/init or any method call yourMethodWithSomeoCndition(.condition1) based on the condition.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Change image to red one
    let dropDownButton = DropDownButton()

    //Call based on your condition
    yourMethodWithSomeoCndition(.condition1)//This condition can change on the fly
}



func yourMethodWithSomeoCndition(_ condition:DropdownCondition)
{
    self.dropDownButton.setImage(condition.getImage(), for: .normal)
}
```